# Control the speed of uitableview insertRowsAtIndexPath animations

Tags: ios, uitableview

I used insertRowsAtIndexPath instead of reloadData.
On the first loading, the animation is too fast because the number of rows is high.

Can I control the speed animation of insertRowsAtIndexPath ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to manipulate the animation speed.

Maybe you can use `scrollToRowAtIndesPath` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Override the insertRowsAtIndexPaths and add custom animation as you like with delay.

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:   (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

 {

for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(320, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Absolutely untested, but you could try this for a five-seconds animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5. animations:^(void){
    [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPath:... animated:NO];
}];
```